# Jumpy/laggy Throttle

Tags: nissan, throttle

Hello I have an issue with my throttle response in 1st and 2nd gear until around 2500rpm,I accelerate and a constant rate and is sluggish until 2500rpm then it jolts the power/ response back to normal then acts like I'm a 16 year old learning manual for the first time, I've unplugged the tps to see if it ran better or worse and it ran worse, thanks in advance car is 1985 Nissan 300zx vg30e

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'd bet disconnecting the TPS would it REALLY run like crud. The TPS is one of the primary inputs the engine uses to know how much fuel to input through the fuel injectors. Without it, the computer doesn't know when you're opening the throttle. Could you please edit your question to put in the year/make/model/engine of the vehicle you have?

Comment: Have you sorted the plugs issue? see https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/76719/10976

Comment: No I'm going to change the rest of the plugs and see were I stand but that will probably be tmr they are a bitch to get at and it's getting late

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Brand new spark plugs misfiring?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/76719/brand-new-spark-plugs-misfiring)