# Posibly Wrong Spark plug gap?

Tags: sparkplugs, rough-idle

So this is an update on my last question, the comments were a mess and I was new to the site I have a 1985 nissan 300zx vg30e and I just changed the spark plugs and its idling really rough and at 550rpm almost like the engine is shivering, the parts desk gave me e3-56 spark plugs I searched it up and supposedly fits the car, say the electrode gap was different, would this behavior make sense?

Comment: So this is exactly what I asked you to check in the question that was linked from this one: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/76721/10976

Comment: Plugs are fine ,check fuel injector wires.

Comment: Just a hint : don’t keep deleting questions to replace with another.